# Do I need to verify interaction with mocks or just check the method inputs and outputs?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Is it necessary to verify the interactions with the Mock objects? So let's say I have a class:

```java
Class A{
    B b;

    public A(B b){
       this.b = b;
    }

    int getObjectFromDatabase(int id){
       Object o = b.get(id);
       // do some extra work
       return result
    }
}
```

Now I'm testing the `getObjectFromDatabase` method. I have passed the Mock object of Class B. Do I need to verify the interaction that `b.get(id)` is being called or not? Or is it a good idea to just check the input and output result I get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, verifying that a stubbed call happened is not necessary, and leads to brittle tests (tests that fail even when the implementation remains correct). In your case, it probably doesn't matter whether `get(id)` is called, or how many times; it only matters that the object returned is correct, and it's likely that a correct result will require calling `b.get(id)` at some point.

Mockito has some [explicit advice in its `verify(T)` Javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)):

> Although it is possible to verify a stubbed invocation, usually **it's just redundant**. Let's say you've stubbed foo.bar(). If your code cares what foo.bar() returns then something else breaks(often before even verify() gets executed). If your code doesn't care what get(0) returns then it should not be stubbed. Not convinced? See [here](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling).

Though it may make sense to `verify(b).get(id)` a certain number of times (including zero) when testing caching or lazy-load behavior, or in other circumstances where the interaction is a crucial part of the tested behavior, strive to test for the *correct output/state* instead of verifying your *expected interactions*.

Comment: Well said. This is one of the hardest lessons to learn about mocking and I still find myself falling foul of it.

Comment: Not verifying a stubbed invocation can get you a "lying" test, though, when no matching call from the code under test occurs; in such a case, the developer would want to either fix the CUT (so the missing call does happen) or to fix the test (by removing an unnecessary stubbing). Ideally, the mocking API should *implicitly* verify every stubbed invocation, to guard against these possibilities.

Comment: Rogério: Implicit verification is the philosophy behind [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/getting-started.html), which Mockito [deliberately forked into "all mocks are nice" behavior](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock). If the call is important to test, verify it explicitly; if it isn't, don't, and at worst you'll have extra stubbing to clean up. Many find that requiring a test fix for every implementation change (not interface/contract change) defeats the point of TDD, but if you disagree you can always call `verifyNoMoreInteractions` on every mock in an `@After` method.

Comment: (I do recognize that you are the creator of JMockit and have [a nice comparison matrix available](http://jmockit.github.io/MockingToolkitComparisonMatrix.html); I'm just saying that both strict and nice mocking have their place.)